Normal Vectors to a Hypersurface
I am reading the Hypersurfaces section on Carroll's GR book. He consider a hypersurface defined by the equation
$$f(x) = f^*$$
where $f$ is some function $f^*$ is a constant. Then he claims that the vector with the vector $$\zeta^\mu=g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\nu f$$ is orthogonal to all vectors to $T_p\Sigma$.
Initially, I thought $\zeta^\mu$ must be zero, since it involves the derivative of a constant function. However, this cannot be the case, as Carroll proceeds to define the normal vector:
$$
n^\mu = \pm \frac{\zeta^\mu}{\vert \zeta^\mu \zeta_\mu \vert^{1/2}}.
$$
If $\zeta^\mu$ were zero, this formula would break down due to division by zero. Clearly, my initial assumption about $\zeta^\mu$ being zero is incorrect. Could someone clarify how $\zeta^\mu$ is orthogonal to $\Sigma$ without relying on my earlier assumption?

The function is not constant!

To elaborate on MBN's comment: just because $f$ is constant on the hypersurface, that doesn't mean that all of its derivatives vanish at points in the hypersurface. Remember that $f$ is actually defined in a larger, ambient space. Its derivative only vanishes in the directions parallel to the hypersurface (this is essentially what you're asked to prove!).

@Danu  I think I got what you're saying. As an example we can consider the radius function in $\mathbb{R}^3$, on a sphere only the partial derivatives in directions orthogonal to the radial direction vanish. And once we contract $\zeta^\mu$ with a $V^\mu$ we get the covariant derivative of $f$ in the direction of $V$ which I think is what actually vanishes.

Does the radial derivative of the radius function, $\partial_{r}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ vanish?

@Buzz No, it is just equal to 1 everywhere.
